# Domino LDAP: how to hide dismissed email addresses from Notes and show them to LDAP

Tags: email, ldap, acl, lotus-domino, roles

In Domino 9.0.x server running LDAP, It seems  that LDAP clients does not honors ACL roles.
I am trying to hide dismissed email addresses using reader role ($Readers field), so only specific people can see them for administration purposes.

I need that an antispam appliance querying Domino via LDAP can see those roles-hidden addresses, to correctly allowing valid recipient control checks.

In this way, relevant email messages can be received while new email addresses will be available to existent external senders.

It seems that LDAP authenticated client does not "own" any roles, and cannot see any role-hidden address, while web browsing on directory with the same authenticated account can.

Anyone use role access with LDAP?
Is there any documentation about limitations on ACL roles in LDAP access?

Comment: Are you granting the LDAP server itself (via its server name or a role in the $Readers field) access to the documents?

Comment: Thank you Richard, Yes, the server is present in ACL as LocalDomainServer, with role active. Nonetheless I added the server name with role, restarted LDAP service, but the result is the same.